# python How to call ob1.fun1.fun2 and handle ob1.fun1 as none?

Tags: python

I tried to use the following code, but looks like ugly

```
tmp = ob1.fun1
result = None
if tmp is not None:
   global result
   result = tmp.fun2
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want `result` to be `None` if `ob1.fun1` is `None` or if `fun2` doesn't exist as an attribute, you could use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and use `None` as a default. Note that `getattr(None, 'attr', something)` will return `something`.

```
result = getattr(ob1.fun1, 'fun2', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission) approach. Wrap it in a try/except and handle your exception accordingly:

```
result = None
try: 
    result = ob1.fun1.fun2
except AttributeError:
    # do your exception handling here
```

You could also use [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) to check if `fun1` is in `ob1`

```
result = None
if hasattr(ob1, 'fun1'):
    res = ob1.fun1.fun2
else:
    print('no fun1 found in ob1')
    # or raise an Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if t.fun1 is not None:
  result = t.fun1.fun2
else:
  result = None
```